# jQuery select right item clicked with each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select the right item which is clicked with each, i have wrote this javascript code it doesn't work when i click on the item it does nothing :

```
jQuery('.kspoiler').each(function() {

 jQuery('.kspoiler').click(function() {

        if ( !jQuery('.kspoiler-content').is(':visible') ) {

            jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-content').show();

            jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-expand').hide();

            jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-hide').show();

        } else {

            jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-content').hide();

            jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-expand').show();

            jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-hide').hide();

        }

    });

});
```

My HTML code is the following :

```
   <div class="kspoiler">
    <div class="kspoiler-header">
        <span class="kspoiler-title">
            Warning: Spoiler!       </span>
        <span class="kspoiler-expand">
            [ Click to expand ]     </span>
        <span style="display:none" class="kspoiler-hide">
            [ Click to hide ]       </span>
    </div>
    <div class="kspoiler-wrapper"><div style="display:none" class="kspoiler-content">
            my content      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

It can be in the page more than on HTML code showed below, my javascript showed below doesn't work. Do-you have any idea how to make it working ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't write !jQuery('.kspoiler-content').is(':visible') - it's select nothing. Also don't need to use $(each) function

```
$('.kspoiler').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':hidden')) {
    $(this).find('.kspoiler-content').show();
    $(this).find('.kspoiler-expand').hide();
    $(this).find('.kspoiler-hide').show();
  } else {
    $(this).find('.kspoiler-content').hide();
    $(this).find('.kspoiler-expand').show();
    $(this).find('.kspoiler-hide').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: It's a bit better like that, but the three item to show or hide aren't changed with that : jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-hide').show();

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use each anymore, since the event listener already gets attached to all the elements with class `.kspoiler` so you don't have to iterate over them anymore. And also, better use the jQuery alias, `$` (unless you have other libraries which might be using the `$`).

```
$('.kspoiler').click(function() {
  // click event handler
  // $(this) refers to the clicked element
});
```

Comment: Yes he must do that if he use an other library who use $ too (like MooTools)

Comment: But he can do that : jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
});

Comment: The problem now is that : jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-hide').show(); does nothing

Answer (score -1):

You add a trigger for ALL item, each time they are...

```
// Loop for all '.kspoiler'
jQuery('.kspoiler').each(function() {
   // Add a trigger for all '.kspoiler'   
   jQuery('.kspoiler').click(function() {
       /***/
   });
});
```

Try to remove your useless loop :

```
// Add a trigger for all 
jQuery('.kspoiler').click(function() {
   /***/
});
```

(With a loop you need to do :)

```
// Loop for all '.kspoiler'
jQuery('.kspoiler').each(function() {
   // Add a trigger for this one   
   jQuery(this).click(function() {
       /***/
   });
});
```

And it's the same think for you condition, you need to select the '.kspoiler-content' on the current clicked :

```
if(jQuery(this).find('.kspoiler-content').is(':hidden') ))
```